# Xcode CPU Usage Profiling in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, cpu-usage, xcode-instruments

I can't seem to find much information on the Instruments too in Xcode which brought me to Stackoverflow.

Is there a way I can see the CPU usage of a particular SDK being used in my iOS application using the CPU Usage tool in Xcode Instruments?

I know I can see the entire application in Xcode with the new gauge tools but I want to dig a little bit deeper and see just the CPU usage of a particular SDK that my iOS application is utilizing. I don't really care to see the entire app as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments (as far as I know) will refill your app, but not the "individual framework"... But from the profiling information you should be able to ascertain which functions (or classes) fuelled which issues and from there work out what frameworks are involved by what you used?

Comment: Ah, okay, I was able to see that. The problem is that it's a pretty complicated framework so it has a lot of functions going on and it's difficult to spot them as they move in and out in Instruments so quickly. Thanks!!! :)